# Create listview in fragment android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

As the title I want to create a listview with custom row in Fragment. My code below.

Fragment class

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment{

public PhotosFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);

    ArrayList<ListviewContactItem> listContact = GetlistContact();
    ListView lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);
    lv.setAdapter(new ListviewContactAdapter(getActivity(), listContact));

    return rootView;
}

private ArrayList<ListviewContactItem> GetlistContact(){
    ArrayList<ListviewContactItem> contactlist = new ArrayList<ListviewContactItem>();

    ListviewContactItem contact = new ListviewContactItem();

    contact.SetName("Topher");
    contact.SetPhone("01213113568");
    contactlist.add(contact);

    contact = new ListviewContactItem();
    contact.SetName("Jean");
    contact.SetPhone("01213869102");
    contactlist.add(contact);

    contact = new ListviewContactItem();
    contact.SetName("Andrew");
    contact.SetPhone("01213123985");
    contactlist.add(contact);

    return contactlist; 
    }   
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class ListviewContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private static ArrayList<ListviewContactItem> listContact;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ListviewContactAdapter(Context photosFragment, ArrayList<ListviewContactItem> results){
    listContact = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(photosFragment);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listContact.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listContact.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_contact_item_name);          
        holder.txtphone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_contact_item_phone);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtname.setText(listContact.get(position).GetName());
    holder.txtphone.setText(listContact.get(position).GetPhone());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView txtname, txtphone;
}
}
```

But when I run the app that display no thing. Could anyone tell me what wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: No, It runs fine but display nothing in fragment.

Comment: I'm also trying the same thing. Can you give me the full source code?

Comment: All thing I posted in my quension. And you can also find out many tutorial about listview on google.

Comment: for me too same does not turn out here my the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254727/actionbar-side-menu-navigation-with-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial

Comment: Hi @gamo can you show me code for layout "contact_item" and 
 Java "ListviewContactItem". I am trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I guess your app crashes because of `NullPointerException`.

Change this

```
ListView lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);
```

to

```
ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);
```

assuming listview belongs to the fragment layout.

The rest of the code looks alright

Edit:

Well since you said it is not working i tried it myself

[image]

Comment: @user3422401 alright i will try your code and get back in 5 minutes. But the codes look alright

Comment: @user3422401 it works fine i only made changes as i suggested in my post.

Comment: @user3422401 do check the snaps works well. SO we need more info. The code posted is fine. Where do you add fragment to the activity. post the xml layouts

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work for me. My Fragment class inside a sliding menu call by MainActivity but I think it's not important.

Comment: @user3422401 AFAIK there is nothing wrong in the code you posted. There is something wrong else where

Comment: Finaly I found where wrong. That in my MainActivy class. Thank you and sorry because waste your time for this.

Comment: Good catch with that, i ran a replace command converting some of my code from "this" to "getActivity()" and totally missed it, couple of hours of googling lead me here. cheers

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you please tell what's the problem with getActivity? YOu have solved my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Please use `ListFragment`. Otherwise, it won't work.

**EDIT 1:**
Then you'll only need `setListAdapter()` and `getListView()`.

Comment: Let me try. I will leave you the result.

Comment: can you give us an example of how ListFragment works?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_fragment.htm

Answer (score 2):

you need to give:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
{
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

inside fragment.

Answer (score 2):

### The inflate() method takes three parameters:

1. The id of a layout XML file (inside R.layout),
2. A parent ViewGroup into which the fragment's View is to be inserted,
3. A third boolean telling whether the fragment's View as inflated from
   the layout XML file should be inserted into the parent ViewGroup.

> In this case we pass false because the View will be attached to the
>   parent ViewGroup elsewhere, by some of the Android code we call (in
>   other words, behind our backs). When you pass false as last parameter
>   to inflate(), the parent ViewGroup is still used for layout
>   calculations of the inflated View, so you cannot pass null as parent
>   ViewGroup .

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
```

So, You need to call `rootView` in here

```
ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment
```

You can use:

```
public class PhotosFragment extends ListFragment
```

It change the methods

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<ListviewContactItem> listContact = GetlistContact();
        setAdapter(new ListviewContactAdapter(getActivity(), listContact));
    }
```

onActivityCreated is void and you didn't need to return a view like in onCreateView

You can see an example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments)