# Why I cannot use Listview within Fragment

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, fragment

How to use `Listview` within `Fragment`. I have implemented almost similar code in an `Activity`, there it worked perfectly. But in case of `Fragment`, I have only modified a little to avoid the errors showed by `Android Studio`. But, it's not working here. 
here is my code:

```
class FragmentMascot : Fragment() {
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view= inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mascot, container, false)
    val listview = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.maskot_list)
    //listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(this) -> this does't work in fragment but worked in activity
    listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(context)
    return view
  }
```

and my `MaskotAdapter` class is:

```
private class MaskotAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {

    private val mContext: Context

    //values can be entered from database too.

    private val maskot_names_list = arrayListOf<String>("","","","")

    private val maskot_details_list = arrayListOf<String>("","","","")

    private val maskot_images_list = arrayListOf<Int>(0,0,0,0)

    init {
      this.mContext = context
    }
    //row count
    override fun getCount(): Int {
      return maskot_names_list.size //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
      return "test String" //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
      return position.toLong()//To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    //renders each row
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
      val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
      val maskot_row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maskot_fragment, parent, false)

      val maskot_names = maskot_row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.maskot_name)
      maskot_names.text=maskot_names_list.get(position)

      // showing ??? if maskot name is empty
      // and giving it a little padding top, to not to keep it on top
      if(maskot_names.text=="")
      {
        maskot_names.text="？？？"
        maskot_names.setPadding( 0, 16, 0, 0)
      }

      val maskot_details = maskot_row.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.maskot_details)
      maskot_details.text=maskot_details_list.get(position)


      if(maskot_images_list.get(position)!=0)
      {
        // showing particular maskot image if maskot image is not empty
        val maskot_image = maskot_row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.maskot_image)
        maskot_image.setImageResource(maskot_images_list.get(position))
      }
      return maskot_row
    }
  }
```

Comment: U should use recycler view instead of ListView, which is more flexible and memory management.

Comment: Not working?? Is it showing some error?

Comment: This looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512833/create-listview-in-fragment-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: yup, but that was for Java, this one is for Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at last. We need to activity as a parameter as well. So, in the code mentioned in the question:

```
listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(context)
```

will be changed into listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(context,activity)
and

```
private class MaskotAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {
```

line should be changed into

```
private class MaskotAdapter(context: Context, activity: Activity): BaseAdapter() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, activity parameter is very important. You can change like:

```
listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(context)
```

will be changed into

```
listview.adapter = MaskotAdapter(context,activity)
```

and

```
private class MaskotAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {
```

line should be changed into

```
private class MaskotAdapter(context: Context, activity: Activity): BaseAdapter() {
```

Hopefully, it will work. But, move to recyclerView if possible, as that is more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Activity context `(getActivity)` in instantiating adapter. Fragment does not own a context.

Answer (score 0):

Does not the list appear? Or is there a fatal exception?

and,

Use RecyclerView.
Calling inflate each time without using the holder pattern in getView () is an inefficient way.

Comment: please attach log.